# Greenlum - How to create Indexed view

Tags: greenplum, hawq

I am trying to design a DW Process and I heard about Indexed views. Actually I want to create a view and it should update automatically when base tables are changed.

Basically, all I need to do is:

- Want to create a regular view
- Then, Want to create a clustered index on that view

Can explain with an query example..

Comment: That isn't supported.  The last time I used an indexed view was in the late 90's with SQL Server because they didn't support partitioning.  Greenplum supports multi-level partitioning so you don't need an indexed view.

Comment: Great thanks to you.